# string interpolation for dynamic html attributes

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

Is it possible to use string interpolation for the below (Note the dynamic attributes)

```
document.body.innerHTML += <form id="digSigForm" action="${myObj.Url}" method="post"><input type="hidden" name="data" value="${myObj.someVal}"></form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the backticks to define a string with string interpollation: ``

Like this:

```
console.log(`1 and 1 make ${1 + 1}`);
```

**This is from the [typescript documentation](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/template-strings.html) :**

> Another common use case is when you want to generate some string out
>   of some static strings + some variables. For this you would need some
>   templating logic and this is where template strings get their name
>   from. Here's how you would potentially generate an html string
>   previously:

```
var lyrics = 'Never gonna give you up';
var html = '<div>' + lyrics + '</div>';
```

> Now with template strings you can just do:

```
var lyrics = 'Never gonna give you up';
var html = `<div>${lyrics}</div>`;
```

> Note that any placeholder inside the interpolation (${ and }) is
>   treated as a JavaScript expression and evaluated as such e.g. you can
>   do fancy math.

```
console.log(`1 and 1 make ${1 + 1}`);
```

Comment: Thanks...What abt the dynamic attributes that I have ?

Comment: @testndtv Can you provide the code where you update your attributes ?

Comment: I mean these are JS objects set in the script...So var myObj.Url = 'xyz.com'

Comment: @testndtv Well so you can set them again with javascript or jquery, please, provide your javascript code

Answer (score 0):

```
document.body.innerHTML += `<form id="digSigForm" action="${myObj.Url}" method="post"><input type="hidden" name="data" value="${myObj.someVal}"></form>`;
```

You forgot the backticks

Answer (score -1):

This currently doesn't work.

I have a string like this, where the row's data attribute is relied upon for some functionality.

```
`<tr class="row ${rowHiddenClass}" data-someId="${this.someId}">
  <td class="cell">${this.Notes}</td>
  <td class="cell amount">$${this.Amount}</td>
</tr>`
```

And it outputs like this within the attribute strings, which breaks that functionality.

```
<tr class="row $" data-someId="$">
  <td class="cell">A nice note</td>
  <td class="cell amount">$4.00</td>
</tr>
```

We may have to do some concatenation for the time being.
I'm not sure yet what the cleaner, simpler solution is.

This works.

```
`<tr class="row ` + rowHiddenClass + `" data-someId="` + this.someId + `">
  <!-- ... -->
</tr>`
```